# How do I display a Gluon map in a View?

Tags: java, javafx, maps, gluon

I am trying out Gluon maps.  I create the following map.fxml:

```
<View fx:id="map" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.runtheworld.MapPresenter">
    <center>
        <Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
    </center>
</View>
```

The Controller/Presenter attempts to show a map:

```
public class MapPresenter {
    @FXML Pane pane;
    MapView  mapView = new MapView();
    MapPoint mapPoint = new MapPoint(56.946,24.10589);  // Riga, Latvia
    
    public void initialize() {
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        sp.getChildren().add(mapView);
        pane.getChildren().add(sp);
        
        // This throws error: "WARNING: sorry, would be too small". Uncommented, it crashes with IndexOutOfBoundsException
        // mapView.setZoom(9);
    }
}
```

The View, MapView is as follows:

```
public class MapView {
    public View getView()
    {
        try {
            View view = FXMLLoader.load(MapView.class.getResource("map.fxml"));
            return view;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
            return new View();
        }
    }
}
```

The Main class is as follows:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static final String MAP_VIEW = "map";
    private final AppManager appManager = AppManager.initialize(this::postInit);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        appManager.addViewFactory(MAP_VIEW, () -> new MapView().getView());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        appManager.start(stage);
    }

    private void postInit(Scene scene) {
        appManager.switchView(MAP_VIEW);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If I do not set zoom in the Controller/Presenter or I set the zoom to a value less than 6 (?), I get the following error: "WARNING: sorry, would be too small" and I can only zoom in, and not back out.  Peering at the code, this error implies a (negative) zoom calculation less than the LayoutBounds().getHeight() which is always 0.0 for a Region (MapView extends Region).

If I set zoom in the Controller/Presenter to a value 6 to 10 or thereabouts, it takes a time to show either a Gluon splash or a blank screen and then sometimes up to a minute or more to finally crash with a stack like so:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 83
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1704)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1648)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doComputeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1501)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doComputeGeomBounds(Parent.java:115)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.computeGeomBoundsImpl(ParentHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.computeGeomBounds(NodeHelper.java:116)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3813)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3775)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3723)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateTxBounds(Node.java:3877)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getTransformedBounds(Node.java:3669)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateBounds(Node.java:771)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1835)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1833)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1833)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1833)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1833)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1833)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2530)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(GtkApplication.java:360)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:515)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:647)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Platform.enterNestedEventLoop(Platform.java:301)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.lambda$installIntoMobileApplication$7(Dialog.java:605)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:101)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:239)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:348)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:79)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer.show(Layer.java:289)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:556)
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.NagScreenPresenter.lambda$showDialog$1(NagScreenPresenter.java:77)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:290)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

which is repeated anytime I move the cursor in the screen but with an increasing length value.  If I enter a zoom value of 12 or higher, no screen gets loaded.

How do I get a map to display correctly in a View?

**EDIT:**
After downloading the Gluon maps code, I added a couple of debug lines to determine what might be happening. In BaseMap, there is a "height" calculation occurring in the zoom() method which is compared to the parent container height.  If this calculation is greater than the parent height, you end up with the arcane and useless error: "WARNING sorry, would be too small".

The parent height seems to be an arbitrary value (I see 1024.0, 1098.0, 1261.0... etc.) and the height calculation often exceeds this seemingly arbitrary parent height value.

The trick is to set your container size eg:

```
sp.setPrefSize(300.d,500.d);
```

and normal service will be resumed.

Comment: the error looks similar to the one you were showing (though incomplete there) in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72043320/what-are-the-correct-min-and-max-values-for-gluon-maps-zooming - did you solve the previous)? if so, you might consider self-answering and accepting your own answer.

Comment: kleopatra: No, the previous question did not involve a View and was in reference to the min/max values of a zoom.  This question is regarding an attempt to display a map at all using a View.

Comment: Have you tried the samples https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/tree/master/samples/mobile and https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloMaps ? Typically a small zoom value like `3` is good enough to start as it requires a very small number of OSM tiles to get downloaded.

Comment: Jose: Yes.  Maps work reasonably with these simple samples - but I cannot get similar code to work in a View (as outlined above) whether zoom is set to a small value or not set at all (which I guess defaults to zoom 0).

Comment: I have resolved the problem.  See EDIT section.

Comment: @ChrisPowell thank you for sharing your solution. I had a spurious and quite similar problem and it appears that your solution has solved it for me!